# Mongo DB Product Price Schema for multiple currencies

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I want to store price information for each product for multiple currencies. The requirements are

1. Prices are different for each currency. What this means is the prices might not match the exchange rate.
2. There is no fixed currencies. Product A might have prices for USD and the other might have prices in USD and EUR. A third product might have prices in JPY.

Currently the prices are stored as a sub document in the product document.

E.g:

```
{
    _id: 'p-1',
    prices: {
        usd: 10000,
        eur: 8000,
        jpy: 1028010,
        ...
    }
}
```

I have been entertaining the idea of moving prices to it's own collection `Price` and storing prices like,

```
{
    prices : ['id1', 'id2']
}
```

and `Price` being

```
{
    _id: 'id1',
    value: 10000,
    currency: 'USD',
    product_id: 'p_1'
}
```

The reason I want to change to this is because it makes it easier to support new currencies, which is important to us. But I'm hesitant because this makes querying for prices a little difficult (and slower imo).

Is there a third option we could use?

Comment: There cannot be too many currencies. So why don't you store prices directly in `product`instead of storing prices's ids?

Comment: Do you mean something like `prices: [{currency: 'USD', value: 10000},{}...]`?

Comment: Exactly. That `prices`array cannot get so big because of number of currencies in use. And you can easily query that array with and index like `db.product.createIndex({"prices.currency": 1, "prices.value": 1})`

Comment: Good Point. Looks like this covers all our requirements.